# How to get result from 2 different table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Scenario: I have 2 query form 2 table, just want to view both query results as a single query result.

Details:

Table: loantrans

```
+-----+----------+---------+---------+---------+
| tid |   date   | account | purpose |    out  |
+-----+----------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1  |2014-08-12|   975   |  Loan   |   5000  |
|  2  |2014-08-12|   975   |Interest |   850   |
|  3  |2014-08-12|   975   |  Loan   |   150   |
|  4  |2014-08-12|   975   |Interest |   5000  |
+-----+----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Table: fdrtrans

```
+-----+----------+---------+---------+---------+
| tid |   date   | account | purpose |    out  |
+-----+----------+---------+---------+---------+
|  1  |2014-08-12|   975   |   FDR   |   5000  |
|  2  |2014-08-12|   975   |Interest |   850   |
|  3  |2014-08-12|   975   |   FDR   |   150   |
|  4  |2014-08-12|   975   | Deposit |   5000  |
+-----+----------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Query 1:

```
SELECT MONTH(`loantrans`.`date`) as month, SUM(`loantrans`.`out`) AS loanout
            FROM loantrans
            WHERE  (`loantrans`.`date` BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-09-20')
            AND (`loantrans`.`purpose` = 'Loan')
            GROUP BY MONTH(`loantrans`.`date`)
            ORDER BY `loantrans`.`date`
```

Result:

```
+-------+---------+
| month | loanout |
+-------+---------+
|   1   |  28000  |
|   2   |  27000  |
|   3   |  10200  |
|   4   |  7000   |
|   5   |  95000  |
|   6   |  2000   |
+-------+---------+
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT MONTH(`fdrtrans`.`date`) as month, SUM(`fdrtrans`.`in`) AS fdr
            FROM fdrtrans
            WHERE  (`fdrtrans`.`date` BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-09-20')
            AND (`fdrtrans`.`purpose` = 'FDR')
            GROUP BY MONTH(`fdrtrans`.`date`)
            ORDER BY `fdrtrans`.`date`
```

Result :

```
+-------+---------+
| month |    fdr  |
+-------+---------+
|   1   |  2000   |
|   2   |  750    |
|   3   |  200    |
|   4   |  180    |
|   5   |  570    |
|   6   |  625    |
+-------+---------+
```

What I want is like

```
+-------+---------+---------+
| month |    fdr  | loanout |
+-------+---------+---------+
|   1   |  2000   |  28000  |
|   2   |  750    |  27000  |
|   3   |  200    |  10200  |
|   4   |  180    |  7000   |
|   5   |  570    |  95000  |
|   6   |  625    |  2000   |
+-------+---------+---------+
```

How to get result like this???

Please check this screenshot for more clear idea of what i'm looking for https://www.dropbox.com/s/kn8z7z4v7sbahf0/Capture4.PNG?dl=0
Database: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8gbgrgvil915efr/bankdb.sql_7.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just join the two queries. Using `WITH` is not necessary, but it greatly enhances the readibility of your query for cases like this.

```
WITH q2 AS
(SELECT MONTH(`fdrtrans`.`date`) as month, SUM(`fdrtrans`.`in`) AS fdr
            FROM fdrtrans
            WHERE  (`fdrtrans`.`date` BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-09-20')
            AND (`fdrtrans`.`purpose` = 'FDR')
            GROUP BY MONTH(`fdrtrans`.`date`)
            ORDER BY `fdrtrans`.`date`)
, q1 AS
(SELECT MONTH(`loantrans`.`date`) as month, SUM(`loantrans`.`out`) AS loanout
            FROM loantrans
            WHERE  (`loantrans`.`date` BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-09-20')
            AND (`loantrans`.`purpose` = 'Loan')
            GROUP BY MONTH(`loantrans`.`date`)
            ORDER BY `loantrans`.`date`)
SELECT q1.month, q1.loanout, q2.fdr
FROM q1
JOIN q2 ON q1.month = q2.month
ORDER BY q1.month
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'q2 AS (SELECT MONTH(`fdrtrans`.`date`) as month, SUM(`fdrtrans`.`in`) AS fdr ' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Union is used to combine the output of select query.

```
select * from loantrans
uninon
select * from fdrtrans
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the JOIN statement to join the two tables together.  Check this website for example on how to do it:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
SELECT s1.month,
       s1.loanout,
       s2.fdr
  FROM(SELECT MONTH(`loantrans`.`date`) as month, SUM(`loantrans`.`out`) AS loanout
         FROM loantrans
        WHERE  (`loantrans`.`date` BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-09-20')
          AND (`loantrans`.`purpose` = 'Loan')
     GROUP BY MONTH(`loantrans`.`date`           
) s1
 JOIN( SELECT MONTH(`fdrtrans`.`date`) as month, SUM(`fdrtrans`.`in`) AS fdr
         FROM fdrtrans
        WHERE  (`fdrtrans`.`date` BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-09-20')
          AND (`fdrtrans`.`purpose` = 'FDR')
     GROUP BY MONTH(`fdrtrans`.`date`)
) s2 ON s1.month = s2.month
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's1 JOIN( SELECT MONTH(`fdrtrans`.`date`) as month, SUM(`fdrtrans`.`in`) AS fdr' at line 9

Comment: Try again please...there was a missing right paranthesis, i corrected it.